# Google Chrome crashes on Flash video

Tags: flash, google-chrome

Twice in the past week I have tried to access a flash video in Google Chrome and my machine has completely rebooted. (e.g.: http://money.cnn.com/video/technology/2011/02/14/t-tt-jeopardy-watson-ibm.cnnmoney/ )

I've done some Googling but have not seen any other users reporting similar problems.

Has anyone here experienced something similar?

I am on a corporate machine with XP SP3 and we do have a fairly aggressive ad blocker on the network so it may just be something internal but any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Version numbers of both Chrome and Flash Player would probably be useful.  Also, if you try again to watch the same video, does your system crash again, or is it unpredictable?

Comment: Thanks CarlF. Chrome - 9.0.597.98 Flash 10.1.103.20 Yes it will do it will do it every time.

Comment: Almost always, reinstalling flash fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the new beta?

> http://www.google.com/intl/en/landing/chrome/beta/